# Consider the function $ \int_0^x [t]dt $ where $ x>0 $ and [t] denotes largest integer less than or equal to t. What is the nature of the function?

Tags: integration, functions, continuity

I have done the following:
$ \int_0^x [t]dt $ can be divided as
$ \int_0^1 [t]dt + \int_1^2 [t]dt + \int_2^3 [t]dt + ... + \int_{x-1}^x [t]dt$
= $ \int_0^1 0dt +\int_1^2 1dt +....$
= $ 1 + 2 + 3 + ....{(x-1)} $
= $ \frac{x(x-1)}{2} $
Therefore, $ f(x) = \frac{x(x-1)}{2} $
If we use this expression to determine the continuity or differentiability of the f(x) then it is continuous and differentiable in [0,x]
However, if we use the original expression $ f(x)= \int_0^x [t]dt $ to determine the nature of the function with the fundamental formulae, 
then the results show that the function is continuous but not differentiable. Where is the fallacy?

Comment: If $x$ is not an integer, the last integral should be $\int_{\lfloor x\rfloor}^x [t]dt$, which is equal to $(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)\lfloor x\rfloor$.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is shown in the graph below.  Between two naturals $n$ and $n+1$ the graph has slope $n$, so it is differentiable.  At the naturals it is not differentiable because the slope is different on the two sides.  You have calculated the values at the naturals correctly, but it has values in between.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your division into several integrals appears to assume $x$ is an integer

Answer (score 0):

An important issue is your argument assumes $x$ is integral, when that is not necessarily the case. This is why your $f\left(x\right) = \frac{x\left(x - 1\right)}{2}$ is not true in all cases. In particular, [CY Aries](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/268334/cy-aries)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3067015/consider-the-function-int-0x-tdt-where-x0-and-t-denotes-largest-i/3067024#comment6323790_3067015) states your summation is missing a last term of $\left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor\right)\lfloor x \rfloor$ (which is $0$ if $x$ is integral). This means the correct function expression for all $x \gt 0$ is

$$f(x) = \frac{x\left(x - 1\right)}{2} + \left(x - \lfloor x \rfloor\right)\lfloor x \rfloor \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$